# Prove that every number to a power greater than 1 can be written as $X^{n+1} = \Sigma_{i=1}^{n}(a_{i}X^{i}-b_{i}Y^{i})$

Tags: number-theory, exponentiation, natural-numbers

Prove that every number to a power greater than 1 can be written as

$X^{n+1} = \Sigma_{i=1}^{n}(a_{i}X^{i}-b_{i}Y^{i})$

for all natural numbers $X,Y$ where $X>Y$.

Further, there exist integers $c,d,e,f$ that result in a unique solution when $a_{i},b_{i}$ are restricted to the ranges $c\leq a_{i}\leq d$ and $e \leq b_{i}\leq f$.

This is more general than a specific [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3171408/how-to-find-a-b-that-satisfy-10n1-sum-i-1na-i10i-b-i9) I asked previously.