# Integer solutions of $x_0+x_1+⋯+x_9=n$ and $1x_1+ 2x_2+ ⋯+9x_9 = m$.

Tags: combinatorics

Count the number of integer solutions to the system of equations: $x_0+x_1+⋯+x_9=n$ and $1x_1+ 2x_2+ ⋯+9x_9 = m$.

Subject to the condition that all the $x_i$'s are non-negative.

Comment: Is * supposed to be an exponent? Please use MathJax to write your quiestions.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Your question is stated as an isolated problem without any context and doesn't show any effort you made to approach the problem. It it likely to attract down votes and close votes. Please edit your question and add some context like why you are interested in this problem and show some effort you made to solve it. What have you tried, where are you stuck?

Comment: This is the number of partitions of $m$ into $n$ (possibly empty) parts not greater than $9$. On what grounds do you think it might have a closed form?

Answer (score 1):

The generating function of the number of solution for the system of equation is as follows
$$
G(t,z)=\frac{1}{(1-tz)(1-tz^2)(1-tz^3)\cdots (1-tz^9)}.
$$
So, the number of sultions is exactly
$$
[t^n z^m]G(t,z)
$$

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to note at one of my previous post:

[How to solve $\left\{\begin{matrix} x_1+x_2+x_3+\cdots+x_k=\Phi_1 \\ x_1+2x_2+3x_3+\cdots+kx_k=\Phi_2 \end{matrix}\right.$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3576060/how-to-solve-left-beginmatrix-x-1x-2x-3-cdotsx-k-phi-1-x-12x-23x/3576088#3576088) where I asked about finding solutions with matrix.

Also, there, I have shown that $m\geq n$.